# What is the difference between data tables & layout tables defining role

Tags: accessibility

In Accessibility What is the different between Data Tables & Layout Tables.

any important to use role="presentation" in  tag.

for example

```
<table role="presentation>
   <table role="presentation"></table>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
  <table role="presentation"></table>
  <table role="presentation"></table>
  <table role="presentation"></table>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second is right!

The [assistive machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_technology) will read the role="presentation" attribute of parent table but they will ignore it, and will continue referring to the second declaration, or vise-versa depending on the way they consume DOM - inside out or outside in.